# HTTP POST request sent via curl against REST server looses JSON parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, curl, http-post, nested-resources

I created a REST server with Rails that manages *Users* and associated *Comments*.
Here is the routes configuration.

```
resources :users do
  resources :comments
end
```

In the controller I only need actions to query and create *Comments*. The exchange format is JSON.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @comments = @user.comments  
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comments }
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @comment = @user.comments.create!(params[:comment])
    redirect_to @user
  end

end
```

I would like to store *Comments* created by a **remote client**. It is an Android application. To test the server I am trying the following *curl* commands, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/255624/85542).

```
curl -X POST -d @comment1.json http://localhost:3000/users/42/comments
curl -X POST -d @comment1.json http://localhost:3000/users/42/comments.json
curl -X POST -d @comment2.json http://localhost:3000/users/42/comments
curl -X POST -d @comment2.json http://localhost:3000/users/42/comments.json
```

I am also not sure how the JSON file has to look like. Here are the variations I tried:
*comment1.json*

```
{
  content:
  {
    message: "Let's see if this works.",
    subject: "JSON via curl"
  }
}
```

... or *comment2.json*

```
{
  message: "Let's see if this works.",
  subject: "JSON via curl"
}
```

When I check the *Comments* on the particular *User* I can see that it has been created, however, the parameters `subject` and `message`, I passed, get lost somewhere!

```
[
  {
    created_at: "2012-08-11T20:00:00Z",
    id: 6,
    message: "null",
    subject: "null",
    updated_at: "2012-08-11T20:00:00Z",
    user_id: 42
  }
]
```

The Rails installation includes the following gems.

```
...
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using json (1.7.4)
...
```

**Question:**

- How can I test the creation of *Comments* via *curl* or with any other suitable tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the *content-type* header with `-H "Content-Type:application/json"`.
I think Rails is looking for the post parameters as form data (eg. `content[subject]='JSON via curl'`).

Further, the JSON file is not valid. JSON keys need to be quoted, too. Use the following file ...

```
{
  "message": "Let's see if this works.",
  "subject": "JSON via curl"
}
```

and send it with one of these commands ...

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @comments2.json http://localhost:3000/users/42/comments
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @comments2.json http://localhost:3000/users/42/comments.json
```

Comment: You have to add quotation marks for JSON keys, you may validate your json with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Both answers are right! I will edit @cjhveal's answer and include your advice, pkubicki. Thank you!