# Default fields for Email params? Testing Email Locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid

My app pipes incoming emails to the `\incoming_emails` route via a POST request from Sendgrid.  From what I can gather, the POST request includes a params hash including including these fields:

`params["to"]
params["from"]
params["subject"]`

For testing, what's the best way to peruse the params hash?  I could easily just use the `logger` to post the content of `params`, but how do I do that locally (I can easily send an email to myself on production, but not sure how to do that locally)?  Is there a list of params for a regular email somewhere?

Comment: I figured out how to send myself an email.  Created an *.eml on my Desktop and used curl to send it.  Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917473/http-post-request-sent-via-curl-against-rest-server-looses-json-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Create an email somewhere on the system (Desktop, easiest). Email format taken from [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/313-receiving-email-with-mailman).

~/Desktop/email.eml

```
Date: Fri, 30 Dec 2011 14:00:00 -0800
From: foo@example.com
Subject: Mailman Test
To: support@example.com

This is a test email for use with Mailman.

Does this work?
```

Then use curl to send the email locally.  Taken from [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917473/http-post-request-sent-via-curl-against-rest-server-looses-json-parameters).

```
curl -X POST -d ~/Desktop/email.eml http://localhost:3000/incoming_emails
```

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to get a hold of the params hash for the email.  If I add, puts params in the controller method that receives the POST request, params only includes params['action'] and params['controller']

Comment: I was using a method in my controller that receives the POST named 'process'.  This must be reserved by Rails since it kept giving me a 0 for 1 argument error.  Still debugging after changing the name of the method.

Comment: Well, I found the fields you get from Sendgrid, and can probably point me in the right direction for local testing: http://sendgrid.com/docs/API%20Reference/Webhooks/parse.html

Comment: Interesting move with the `.eml` file.  I would have just done a fake post request.  Would love to see a gist when you're all done though

Comment: Still beating myself up over this one today, figured I'd sleep on it.  Definitely will prepare a gist when I've got it figured out.  Started playing with RSpec to test locally, but would still like to learn how to get the '.eml' file to be read via POST through curl.

Comment: Can't get the .eml to parse out, but found out to get a params hash to Rails you'll have to format the curl command a bit differently.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860654/nested-params-with-curl